# Error in running the pytorch model: Missing key(s) in state_dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to run a script from [this repo](https://github.com/cxzhou95/XLSR) which tests a PyTorch model. I simply run it through `python test.py` using its defaults values (with the correct path to `best.pt`). But when running, it gives the following error.

What is the problem? How to fix it?

This is the snippet in `test.py`:

```
   device = 'cuda:' + str(opt.device) if opt.device != 'cpu' else 'cpu'
    model = XLSR(opt.SR_rate)
    
    # load pretrained model
    if opt.model.endswith('.pt') and os.path.exists(opt.model):
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(opt.model, map_location=device))
    else:
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join(opt.save_dir, 'best.pt'), map_location=device))
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XLSR\test.py", line 110, in <module>
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join(opt.save_dir, 'best.pt'), map_location=device))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 2152, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for XLSR:
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "Gblocks.0.conv0.conv2d_block.0.weight", "Gblocks.0.conv0.conv2d_block.0.bias", "Gblocks.0.conv0.conv2d_block.1.weight", "Gblocks.0.conv0.conv2d_block.1.bias", "Gblocks.0.conv0.conv2d_block.2.weight", "Gblocks.0.conv0.conv2d_block.2.bias", "Gblocks.0.conv0.conv2d_block.3.weight", "Gblocks.0.conv0.conv2d_block.3.bias", "Gblocks.1.conv0.conv2d_block.0.weight", "Gblocks.1.conv0.conv2d_block.0.bias", "Gblocks.1.conv0.conv2d_block.1.weight", "Gblocks.1.conv0.conv2d_block.1.bias", "Gblocks.1.conv0.conv2d_block.2.weight", "Gblocks.1.conv0.conv2d_block.2.bias", "Gblocks.1.conv0.conv2d_block.3.weight", "Gblocks.1.conv0.conv2d_block.3.bias", "Gblocks.2.conv0.conv2d_block.0.weight", "Gblocks.2.conv0.conv2d_block.0.bias", "Gblocks.2.conv0.conv2d_block.1.weight", "Gblocks.2.conv0.conv2d_block.1.bias", "Gblocks.2.conv0.conv2d_block.2.weight", "Gblocks.2.conv0.conv2d_block.2.bias", "Gblocks.2.conv0.conv2d_block.3.weight", "Gblocks.2.conv0.conv2d_block.3.bias".
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "Gblocks.0.conv0.weight", "Gblocks.0.conv0.bias", "Gblocks.1.conv0.weight", "Gblocks.1.conv0.bias", "Gblocks.2.conv0.weight", "Gblocks.2.conv0.bias".
```

Answer (score 1):

Initial comment: the weights you are using are, at least named, 1d convolutions, but your model wants 2d convolutions. Considering the repo is super-resolution (i.e. computer vision which almost exclusively uses 2d over 1d conv), my best guess is that the weights are for a different model structure.